# Can we list all videos in vimeo databse through api?

Tags: vimeo-api

Is it possible to get a list (csv/xls) of all the videos on the account through the api?

Answer (score 0):

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos
```

This method returns all the videos that match custom search criteria.

You can learn more methods in this link from [Vimeo Documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#search_videos)